# gstreamer error: file is in the wrong format

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264

I want to visualize the h264 stream from a videocamera, but using a normal pipeline that I have found it gaves ne this error:

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\bin>gst-launch-1.0.exe udpsrc caps="application/x-rtp, medi
a=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int
)96" port=5002 ! queue2 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink sync=false
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0: Coul
d not decode stream.
Additional debug info:
gstrtph264depay.c(1205): gst_rtp_h264_depay_process (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/G
stRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0:
Undefined packet type
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0: Coul
d not decode stream.
Additional debug info:
gstrtph264depay.c(1205): gst_rtp_h264_depay_process (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/G
stRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0:
Undefined packet type
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0: The st
ream is in the wrong format.
Additional debug info:
gstrtph264depay.c(1216): gst_rtp_h264_depay_process (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/G
stRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0:
NAL unit type 26 not supported yet
Execution ended after 0:00:00.048525141
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

probably there is a problem with rtph264depay but I want to know if the problem is in the pipeline or in the camera output...

thank you!

Comment: what pipeline you have used for streaming the video data from camera, can you share it? So, that it will helps to analyze the problem.

Comment: I have solved the problem, anyway thank you! Do you know how to make my question solved? I'm new in this site :)

Comment: just answer your question in the below editor, and accept it that's it.

Comment: Can you please post your solution? Thanks